# Manage Windows App Execution Aliases from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, app-execution-alias

Is it possible to turn off app execution aliases from Powershell?

I am ideally looking for a command like:

```
PS> Disable-AppExecutionAlias python
```

Right now, the only way I can find to do this is by going to the Start menu and searching for "Manage app execution aliases", then disabling them manually. I'd like to be able to do this programatically.

[image]

*Context*: I am writing a script to set up relatively simple workstations and trying to eliminate all the manual steps.

#### EDIT:

I am aware of `Set-Alias` and `Remove-Alias`, but these are PowerShell aliases, not app execution aliases as shown in the screenshot above.

Comment: It looks like these are defined in the registry at: `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\`. I tried manually defining some new ones, but it seems that the .exe name may have to be registered somewhere first?

Comment: The `python.exe` and `python3.exe` app execution aliases are part of the Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller UWP app. This application cannot be removed (the AppX package's `NonRemovable` property is `true`). Removing the `python.exe` and `python3.exe` files (actually NTFS reparse points) from `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\WindowsApps` is functionally equivalent to toggling the app execution alias in the Settings app. Unfortunately, their removal is not noticed by the Settings app, as it uses its own persistence (via Windows.StateRepositoryPS.dll) to keep track of the toggle state.

Answer (score 3):

## Quick and dirty

Here is how far I got:

```
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

That is how you can get rid of the programs in your example. When you disable and re-enable the respective entry in the control panel it will be recreated. So there is little damage done here and you get what you were looking for.

Finding the proper solution to this problem and understanding what's going on here requires more time to research. But doing such kind of things in Windows is not my day job nor my area of expertise, Linux is more of my interest.

## Manually creating and alias for applications installed with winget

The thing that actually got me into researching this was that a program like `jq` installed through winget would not be on the path and thus not being found. Kind of the reverse what you were asking. So I dug around in the filesystem, registry and online searches.

For `jq` right now I'm doing this in PowerShell:

```
# Reg2CI (c) 2022 by Roger Zander
if((Test-Path -LiteralPath "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jq.exe") -ne $true) {
  New-Item "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jq.exe" -force -ea SilentlyContinue 
};
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jq.exe' 
  -Name '(default)' -Value "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\stedolan.jq_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe\jq-win64.exe" 
  -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\jq.exe' 
  -Name 'Path' -Value "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Microsoft\WinGet\Packages\stedolan.jq_Microsoft.Winget.Source_8wekyb3d8bbwe" 
  -PropertyType String -Force -ea SilentlyContinue;
```

Sorry about the super long lines, apparently only very few people using Windows care about readable code and line length.

## UWP

This seems to be related to [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap5-appexecutionalias). Here is a [popular example](https://github.com/felixse/FluentTerminal/blob/295e27ae79a8be8b273b19bec6201c3767aa4897/FluentTerminal.Package/Package.appxmanifest#L46), here is [another question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55426605/how-to-properly-set-appexecutionalias-so-the-program-could-be-launched-from-comm).

Sorry I would like to write and research more about this, but I'm complety sidetracked here.